# Are there any coins which BTC does not trade with?

Tags: exchanges, altcoin

For example, ADABTC, LTCBTC, are there any which do not trade with BTC.

If so, are there any that do not trade with BTC, LTC and ETH?

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense.  People are free to trade anything for anything else.  It might be that certain pairs are more convenient to trade than others, because of market liquidity or availability of exchanges, but there is no coin that inherently "does not trade" with BTC.

Comment: Nate, I missed out the part about exchanges.

Certain exchanges do not trade with certain coins, or they limit what you can use to trade one coin with another. 

I was wondering whether there were any that did not allow BTC to be traded on their platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some out there in some minor exchanges, but it is very very unlikely to be this case. BTC is the dominant liquid currency in the cryptocurrency economy. Most altcoins will trade against it. Perhaps you could find some coins that do not trade against BTC here https://www.coingecko.com/en/exchanges majority does.

BTC is more dominant than ETH at the moment for liquidity

Comment: Do you own that company? If so, do you know if they have hourly/minute historical data for all coins on their platform since inception?

Answer (score 0):

i have traded on several exchanges. i have never seen a cryptocurrency which you could not trade with bitcoin or ethereum on any exchange.